# vb6 broadcast to all network interface

Tags: networking, vb6

pc >>> virtual machine 
pc client.exe | virtual machine running server.exe
pc connects to server.exe no problem then binds the UDP to it so it can send a message.

now that these 2 are connected and broadcast message is being sent pc to virtual every second when I launch a multiplayer game on both pc and virtual machine.
pc can't see the hosted game from a virtual machine why not?

I read online you send UDP broadcast packets but it does not mention what type of packet and what to send so I just used some normal data instead and the hosted game is not being detected.

also, I think this is not sending broadcast to all network interfaces how do I do that

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
 wss.RemoteHost = "255.255.255.255"   ' Must have remote IP Address
 'ws1.Bind 12345                       ' Must Bind our Local Port Number
 wss.RemotePort = 1234                ' Must have Remote Port Number
 wss.SendData wss.LocalHostName & vbNewLine & wss.LocalIP & vbNewLine & wss.LocalPort & vbNewLine
 Caption = "Client 2: IP = " & wss.LocalIP & ", Port = " & wss.LocalPort
End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.solidautomation.com/bryon/Using_UDP_and_Winsock_in_Visual_Basic_6.htm
It looks about there.  What is your `wss` object?  A standard `Winsock`?  You could try to set the protocol as in the example above:  `wss.Protocol = sckUDPProtocol`.  Other than that, 1) verify your payload, and 2) try to find another tool to detect the broadcast other than your game and at least limit your possibilities for failure.. Once you know your code is publishing "something", that limits what could be failing.  Oh, and make sure you don't have a firewall on the target machine.